# Changing column order with SQL ALTER FUNCTION creates strange results in dependent functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

It seems that when you modify the column order of a function using ALTER FUNCTION, SQL does not update dependent functions and can cause completely incorrect results to be returned.

Is there a way to force dependent functions to be updated automatically without requiring each one be done manually?

An example:

```
create function dbo.Test1 ()
returns table
AS
return
(
    select 1 as [One], 2 as [Two]   
)

GO

create function dbo.Test2 ()
returns table
AS
return
(
    select * from Test1()
)

GO
```

These work as expected:

```
select * from Test1()
select * from Test2()
```

Both return:

```
One         Two
----------- -----------
1           2
```

Now, if we modify the function:

```
alter function dbo.Test1 ()
returns table
AS
return
(
    select 2 as [Two], 1 as [One]   
)

GO
```

And query the results:

```
select * from Test1()
```

Returns:

```
Two         One
----------- -----------
2           1
```

as expected, but:

```
select * from Test2()
```

Returns:

```
One         Two
----------- -----------
2           1
```

So, we now have the old column ordering, but with the the values in the new positions - meaning that the values in this example are transposed.

Comment: Do your real functions contain `SELECT *`?  This would be a bad idea.

Comment: Never, ever, ever, ever (etcetera), use `SELECT *` in production code. This is just one problem caused by its use, there are others. Using column names avoids this particular problem.

Comment: For even more fun, try altering `Test1` to include a third column. You'll see that `SELECT * FROM Test2()` will still only return two columns. And for maximum fun, remove a column -- you will now get an error stating "View or function 'Test2' has more column names specified than columns defined." The moral of this story: don't use `SELECT *` in general, but especially not in functions and views.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `sp_refreshsqlmodule` when dealing with UDF. This will refresh the metadata and return the correct columns.

```
EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule 'dbo.Test2'
```

sp_refreshsqlmodule will update the metadata for the UDF. Metadata for UDFs (such as parameters or data types) can become outdates because of changes to underlying objects - which is what is happening in your example. I have tested it, using your example, and it is working as expected.

For more info on `sp_refershsqlmodule` see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx).

As, Matthew Brophy points out, the correct solution is to not use `SELECT *` in UDFs - rather explicitly list the column names in the `SELECT`.

Comment: This does work.  Unfortunately, it does still require manual intervention for all dependent functions, so while helpful, it isn't perfect.

I think the real answer is to explicitly list the column names.

Comment: Looks good, +1. Also, @MatthewBrophy, such is the nature of the beast ;-). If you want automation, create a DDL trigger to capture ALTER FUNCTION events and then look for any dependent objects using `sys.sql_dependencies` and `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` and call `sp_refreshsqlmodule` on what is found. Sure, not using `SELECT *` is nearly always the way to go, but would it help in the case of a removed field?

Comment: @srutzky: and then don't forget to add triggers for tables and views, just in case those are referenced with `SELECT *`... that way lies madness. I mean, you can get it to work, but madness. I'd say, if you want automation, use `sys.sql_modules(definition)` to check for every instance of `SELECT *` and fix it at the source. :-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert You beat me to the comment as I was updating my prior one and went over the 5 minute limit. I was clarifying that I am _not_ arguing against getting rid of `SELECT *`; I very much agree that it is 99.5% of the time pure e-v-i-l. I was just saying that I don't think that alone will prevent the need of ever using `sp_refreshsqlmodule` or even `sp_refreshview`.